# Error con contentProvider Android

Tags: android, content-provider

Estoy intentando obtener unos datos mediante un content provider con Android, y obtengo el siguiente error:

> 2020-05-02 16:33:29.496 18472-18472/es.ubu.lsi E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: idLlamada
>   2020-05-02 16:33:29.497 18472-18472/es.ubu.lsi E/es.ubu.lsi.provider.ContactsProvider: Error in provider inserting data.
>   2020-05-02 16:33:29.502 18472-18472/es.ubu.lsi E/es.ubu.lsi.CallsActivity: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

El código de la clase **CallsActivity** es:

```
 * 
 */
package es.ubu.lsi;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import es.ubu.lsi.modelo.Llamada;
import es.ubu.lsi.provider.CallsProvider;


public class CallsActivity extends Activity {

    /** TAG */
    private static String TAG = CallsActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

    /** List of calls. */
    private List<Llamada> datos = new ArrayList<Llamada>();

    /**
     * onCreate.
     * 
     * @param savedInstanceState saved state
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_llamadas);

        // Load the calls from the content provider
        getCallsFromProvider();

        for (Llamada c : datos) {
            if (c == null)
                break;
            Log.v(TAG, c.getFechaLlamada() + " " + c.getHoraLlamada());
        }

        AdaptadorCalls adaptador = new AdaptadorCalls(this);

        GridView gridOpciones = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewLlamadas);
        gridOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);

        // Set listener...
        gridOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Deleted record "
                                + datos.get(arg2).getIdLlamada());

                    }
                });

    }

    private void getCallsFromProvider() {
        try {
            // Projection of calls data
            String[] projection = new String[] {
                    CallsProvider.Llamadas.ID_LLAMADA,
                    CallsProvider.Llamadas.COL_FECHA,
                    CallsProvider.Llamadas.COL_HORA};

            Uri clientesUri = CallsProvider.CONTENT_URI; // URI Provider

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Log.v(TAG, "Get content resolver");

            // Do query.
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(clientesUri, projection, // Columns to
                    // return
                    null, // Query condition (where)
                    null, // Args of query condition, empty in this case
                    null); // Order clause, empty in this case

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // if there are records...
                do {
                    // load calls data record
                    int idLlamada = cursor.getInt(0);
                    String fechaLlamada = cursor.getString(1);
                    String horaLlamada = cursor.getString(2);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Date d1 = new Date();
                    Date d2 = new Date();
                    d1 = dateFormat.parse(fechaLlamada);
                    d2 = timeFormat.parse(horaLlamada);
                    datos.add(new Llamada(idLlamada, d1, d2));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext()); // move next if exists
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for data views.
     * 
     * @author <A HREF="mailto:rmartico@ubu.es">Raúl Marticorena</A>
     * @version 1.0
     *
     */
    private class AdaptadorCalls extends ArrayAdapter {

        /** Context */
        Activity context;

        /**
         * Constructor. 
         * 
         * @param context context
         */
        AdaptadorCalls(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.calls, datos);
            this.context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Load the views with current data.
         * 
         * @param position position
         * @param convertView view
         * @param parent parent
         */
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View item = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (item == null) { // first time
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calls, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.idLlamada = (TextView) item
                        .findViewById(R.id.lblIdLlamada);
                holder.fecha = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.lblFecha);
                holder.hora = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.lblHora);

                item.setTag(holder);
            } else { // view previously loaded
                holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
            }

            holder.idLlamada.setText(Integer.toString(datos.get(position)
                    .getIdLlamada()));
            holder.fecha.setText(datos.get(position).getFechaLlamada().toString());
            holder.hora.setText(datos.get(position).getHoraLlamada().toString());

            return (item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View holder.
     * 
     * @author rmartico
     * 
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView idLlamada;
        TextView fecha;
        TextView hora;
    }
}
```

El código de la clase **CallsProviders** es:

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

import es.ubu.lsi.persistencia.DBSqliteHelper;

public class CallsProvider extends ContentProvider {
    /** Tag. */
    private static final String TAG = CallsProvider.class.getName();

    /** Dababase name. */
    public static final String DB_EXAMPLE = "DBExample";

    /** Definición del CONTENT_URI. */
    private static final String uri = "content://es.ubu.lsi.provider/llamadas";

    /** Parse uri of content provider. */
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(uri);

    /** Codes used in UriMatcher. */
    private static final int LLAMADAS = 1;
    private static final int LLAMADAS_ID = 2;

    /** Uri matcher. */
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    /**
     * Inner class with columns declarations.
     */
    public static final class Llamadas implements BaseColumns {
        /** Constructor. */
        private Llamadas() {
        }

        /** Column names. */
        public static final String ID_LLAMADA = "idLlamada";
        public static final String COL_FECHA = "FechaLlamada";
        public static final String COL_HORA = "HoraLlamada";
    }

    /** Database helper. */
    private DBSqliteHelper dbSqliteHelper;

    /** Database version. */
    private static final int BD_VERSION = 1;

    /** Contacts table */
    private static final String CALLS_TABLE = "llamadas";

    /**
     * Inits UriMatcher
     */
    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI("net.sgoliver.android.ejemplo", "llamadas",
                LLAMADAS);
        uriMatcher.addURI("net.sgoliver.android.ejemplo", "llamadas/#",
                LLAMADAS_ID);
    }

    /**
     * onCreate. Inits database helper.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbSqliteHelper = new DBSqliteHelper(getContext(), DB_EXAMPLE, null,
                BD_VERSION);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Query.
     *
     * @param uri
     *            uri provider
     * @param projection
     *            columns
     * @param selection
     *            query
     * @param selectionArgs
     *            args
     * @param sortOrder
     *            order
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor c = null;
        // If it is a query with an ID, builds WHERE clause
        String where = selection;
        if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == LLAMADAS_ID) {
            where = "idLlamada=" + uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = dbSqliteHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // gets
            // database
            // Execute query and get the data cursor.
            c = db.query(CALLS_TABLE, projection, where, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in provider inserting data.");
        }
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * Insert.
     *
     * @param uri
     *            uri
     * @param values
     *            values
     */
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        long regId = 1;
        Uri newUri = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = dbSqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            // Insert
            regId = db.insert(CALLS_TABLE, null, values);
            newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, regId);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in provider inserting data.");
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return newUri;
    }

    /**
     * Update.
     */
    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {

        int cont = -1;

        // If it is a query with an ID, builds WHERE clause
        String where = selection;
        if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == LLAMADAS_ID) {
            where = "idLlamada=" + uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = dbSqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            cont = db.update(CALLS_TABLE, values, where, selectionArgs);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in provider updating data.");
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return cont;
    }

    /**
     * Delete.
     */
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        int cont = -1;

        // Si es una consulta a un ID concreto construimos el WHERE
        String where = selection;
        if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == LLAMADAS_ID) {
            where = "idLlamada= " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = dbSqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            cont = db.delete(CALLS_TABLE, where, selectionArgs);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in provider deleting data.");
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return cont;
    }

    /**
     * Gets type of uri.
     */
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match) {
            case LLAMADAS:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.es.ubu.lsi.modelo.llamada";
            case LLAMADAS_ID:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.es.ubu.lsi.modelo.llamada";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

El código de la clase ***DBSqliteHelper*** es:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * DBSqliteHelper. Database service class.
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class DBSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // DDL SQL statements
    public static final String sqlCreateContactos = "CREATE TABLE [Contactos] ("
            + "[idContacto] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "[nombre] VARCHAR(50)  NULL," + "[apellidos] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,"
            + "[telefonoMovil] VARCHAR(50)  NULL)";

    public static final String sqlCreateLlamadas = "CREATE TABLE [Llamadas] ("
            + "[idLlamada] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "[idContacto] INTEGER  NOT NULL," + "[FechaLlamada] DATE  NULL,"
            + "[HoraLlamada] TIME  NULL,"
            + "FOREIGN KEY(idContacto) REFERENCES Contactos(idContacto))";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context context
     * @param name name 
     * @param factory factory 
     * @param version version
     */
    public DBSqliteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

    }

    /**
     * On create database.
     * 
     * @param db database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Executing DDL with create tables
        db.execSQL(sqlCreateContactos);

        db.execSQL(sqlCreateLlamadas);

        // Insert data examples
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Contactos (nombre, apellidos, telefonoMovil) "
                + "VALUES ('Raúl', 'Marticorena Sánchez', '999999999')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Contactos (nombre, apellidos, telefonoMovil) "
                + "VALUES ('Carlos', 'López Nozal', '888888888')");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO [Llamadas] (idContacto, fechaLlamada, horaLlamada) VALUES"
                + "(1, '2012-02-02', '12:00:00')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO [Llamadas] (idContacto, fechaLlamada, horaLlamada) VALUES"
                + "(1, '2012-02-02', '12:00:01')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO [Llamadas] (idContacto, fechaLlamada, horaLlamada) VALUES"
                + "(2, '2012-02-02', '12:00:00')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO [Llamadas] (idContacto, fechaLlamada, horaLlamada) VALUES"
                + "(2, '2012-02-02', '12:00:02')");

    }

    /**
     * On upgrade database.
     * 
     * @param db database
     * @param previousVersion previous version number
     * @param newVersion new version number
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int previousVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        // NOTE: easy solution dropping tables and creating again

        // Remove tables...
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Contactos");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Llamadas");
        // Create new versions... (only create tables again in this solution)
        db.execSQL(sqlCreateContactos);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreateLlamadas);
    }
}
```

Comment: la probaste alguna vez y después agregaste alguna columna??

Answer (score 0):

El error se describe aquì:

> SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: idLlamada

indica que tratas de acceder a una columna llamada `idLlamada` pero esta no existe.

---

Veo que estas creando la Tabla con la columna :

```
 public static final String sqlCreateLlamadas = "CREATE TABLE [Llamadas] ("
            + "[idLlamada] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "[idContacto] INTEGER  NOT NULL," + "[FechaLlamada] DATE  NULL,"
            + "[HoraLlamada] TIME  NULL,"
            + "FOREIGN KEY(idContacto) REFERENCES Contactos(idContacto))";
```

y estas definiendo la variable con el nombre correcto para accedera la columna.

```
public static final String ID_LLAMADA = "idLlamada";
```

en este caso el problema se puede deber a que creaste una estructura de la tabla pero esta no contiene la columna o tiene otro nombre, en este caso te sugiero eliminar completamente la aplicaciòn de tu dispositivo y subirla nuevamente.

También puedes cambiar la versión de la base de datos.

```
/** Database version. */
    private static final int BD_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias por la respuesta, he intentado eso muchas otras veces y no me da resultado. Tengo otra funcionalidad que es exactamente igual pero con un listad de contactos, y esa funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Aumenta la versión de la base de datos y sube nuevamente la aplicación.